# typeahead bootstrap displaying dropdown but without li labels

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using angularjs and bootstrap. some of my pages integrated with "typeahead" code.

when I write a character in text field, the dropdown displays but with empty labels.

when I click on any empty label, it fills the textfield with correct value.

The problem is, dropdown not displays labels

any solution.

```
<input type="text" class="order_input" ng-model="selected_address" 
  typeahead="rest as rest.name for rest in  searchTerms($viewValue,'restaurants/typeahead_address/',{type:restaurant_type})" 
   placeholder="Enter Postal Code or Address.." />
```

Comment: Please put your code for more details, this question is not precise enough.

Comment: <input type="text" class="order_input" ng-model="selected_address" typeahead="rest as rest.name for rest in searchTerms($viewValue,'restaurants/typeahead_address/',{type:restaurant_type})" placeholder="Enter Postal Code or Address.." />

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about `typeahead`
But I actually apply what you are talking about as follows

```
<input type="text" class="order_input" list="dataSource" placeholder="Enter Postal Code or Address.." />
    <datalist id="dataSource" >
        <option ng-repeat="rest in allData">{{rest.name}}</option>            
    </datalist>
```